# Error while adding labels to plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to add labels to my plot that shows CO2 emissions vs. GDP. I am getting object 'GDP' not found error..

```
library(UsingR)
plot(CO2 ~ GDP, data=emissions, pch = 20, main='CO2 emissions vs. GDP')
text(CO2, GDP, row.names(emissions), cex= 0.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to plot it correctly, but it will still be difficult to visualise all of them, because the points overlap quite a bit:

```
library(UsingR)
plot(CO2 ~ GDP, data = emissions, pch = 20, main = 'CO2 emissions vs. GDP')
text(x = emissions$GDP, y = emissions$CO2 + 500, labels = row.names(emissions), cex = 0.7)
```

[image]